# shell script works but not as a systemd service

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, systemd

`systemctl status` and `journelctl -xe` shows SUCCESS. But on `ps -A`, "cat" is not there, but executing shell scripts alone works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/stty  -F /dev/ttyS4 raw -echo  921600
/bin/stty  -F /dev/ttyGS0 raw -echo 9600
/bin/cat /dev/ttyS4 > /dev/ttyGS0&
/bin/cat /dev/ttyGS0 > /dev/ttyS4&
echo 'cat serial ports done'
```

```
[Unit]
Description=cats commands

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /catscripts.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: sorry my alignments were wrong. I am new to this forum. Please bear with me. I will try to correct this alignment issues

Comment: you can read about formatting here https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: I think the problem lies in making my CAT commands as background processes with & symbols at line end. Because my previous STTY commands succeed and even if i insert a test ECHO command as the last entry, it succeeds and i could see it in journalctl -xe output